# VScode autocomplete doesn't work for CSS files

Tags: visual-studio-code

Autocomplete for CSS is not working in VSCode.

[image]

Usually, if I start writing an statement inside a CSS file, VSCode has an intenseness, which suggested all possible options.
But as you can see, it doesn't work inside my css file.

Any help?

Comment: try this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss

Comment: That's odd.  CSS intellisense is built-in and should work without an extension.  What is the language mode indicated in the lower right-hand corner for this file?  Does "Ctrl+space" bring up suggestions?

Comment: Thanks. I think this has fixed it. The language mode for my css file was on postcss. After changing it to css, the IntelliSense is now working fine.

Answer (score 74):

I had the same issue after I installed the VSCode extension `PostCSS Language Support`,

I fixed it by disabling the extension.

Answer (score 17):

If you have `PostCSS Language Support` installed add the following config in your settings.

```
{
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "postcss": "css"
  }
}
```

Comment: This works for me. I just have to go to `settings.json` to add this config without disabling the `PostCSS` extension

Answer (score 12):

If you are using the [PostCSS Language Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=csstools.postcss) plugin, you may want to additionally install the [PostCSS Intellisense and Highlighting](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vunguyentuan.vscode-postcss) plugin. Follow the plugin instructions to enable emmet support.

Answer (score 10):

I realized that at the bottom right of the screen, my language mode was set to **postCSS**. So simply clicking there and changing it to CSS solved this. Images are for illustration

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you might have installed some extensions which prevent css form doing autocomplete, uninstalling the latest extensions (from the time it started happening) will resolve your problem

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

I also got stuck on the same problem, unable to auto-complete the properties in CSS files. I had done many restarts but the situation couldn't be resolved!
Often, sometimes uninstalling and re-installing didn't work, shows the same issues.
Their are some steps that helped me to resolve the problem:

- **Uninstall** the VS Code.[Uninstalling VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ny4HV.png)
- Run "Win+R" and type *"%APPDATA%\Code"*, then press enter or OK, and there remove the User folder completely.[Remove the User Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bjKk.png)
- Run "Win+R" and type *"%USERPROFILE%"* and remove .vscode folder. [Remove .vscode Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeBDk.png)
- **Re-install** VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the all unwanted extention installed on vs code and reload the vs code it will work .

Answer (score 0):

You may have installed an extension/package that changed the language mode (usually to Postcss).
Here's what to do: On your visual studio code editor, open your [style].css page. Go the status bar (sits at the bottom of the VS Code workbench) ensure the language mode is on 'Css'. Changing it to Css may help.
Here's a picture.
[image: Visual studio code editor]

Answer (score -1):

[Slove CSS ISSUE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0AdO.png)

[All of issue this in the post CSS Extention  if you uninstal or disable this your problem is solve

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same problem after installing `PostCSS Language Support`

#### solution

`Just disable PostCSS Language Support, and it will be fixed!`