# Autocomplete for CSS in a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to get autocomplete for CSS in my jsJScode? I am using VS-Code.

I can manipulate CSS without trouble, it just doesn't show me the auto suggestions.

like `document.queryselector("myclass").` ----nothing appears after the dot like eg. `style`.

Also is to say, autocomplete works in the CSS itself. Just not in JS file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VScode autocomplete doesn't work for CSS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61171247/vscode-autocomplete-doesnt-work-for-css-files)

Comment: you can install an extension called "CSS-in-JS" from the Visual Studio Code Marketplace

Comment: Hello Thanks for the tip. It still doesnt work. In my tutorial Video it all appears. But not in my code. i want to change simply the background color of my class in css. 
so document.querryselector(".myclass").[style.backgroundColor]<--- this should appear but it doesnt. Also not with Tabnine

Answer (score 1):

Try a vs-code extension "tabnine"

Comment: Note: this answer misunderstands the question (I also misunderstood it, so no shame)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I wrote this answer having completely misunderstood the question based on the title and having missed something crucial about the question in the body. Now that I understand the question, it's a duplicate (I've cast my dup-vote). But I leave the answer I wrote just in case it helps someone else:

I imagine that getting what you're looking for would be complicated to implement- perhaps even impossibly to implement in some sort of ideal sense. Some examples:

- Imagine you have HTML page file a.html and b.html, CSS files c.css, and JS file d.js. a.html and b.html both include d.js, but only a.html includes d.js. Now what should happen? Should IntelliSense provide classnames from c.css knowing that they won't exist for d.js when it is included in b.html?
- Imagine that you have some CSS file(s) that are not in the repository, but will be provided in the production environment by the server. Now what? You'd need to have some mechanism to tell IntelliSense about that file(s).

What I'd suggest that you look into is CSS modules and https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-plugin-css-modules. It's a thing of its own and will require quite a bit of restructuring and development / built tooling setup, but it has its advantages.

You might also be interested to know that there are options to write CSS in JS (look at Emotion and styled-components), but that's quite a different approach to what you're looking for.