# vscode html classes/id in javascript, autocomplete

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense

How to make it so that in vscode, in javascript files, the names of classes / identifiers are taken from the html code, which is located in the same folder or inside the js folder, which is in the same folder as the html file?

[image]

Comment: What? Please can you provide code or explain it better because I am so confused.

Comment: I want that when writing the js code, there are class names that are in the html file. (It is very inconvenient to copy the names of classes or rewrite them), I want them to be automatically added.
On the screen (in js app.js file) should be "ineedthisinjs" instead of "no suggestions"

Comment: see also related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76578004/11107541