# Are there an extension for vs code to highlight classes from sass in js files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, frontend

are there extensions for vs code that help parse classes from .module.sass, as in webstorm?
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNWxi.png)

Tried various extensions such as [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fengzhu.css-module-intellisense&ssr=false#review-details), [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iceworks-team.iceworks-style-helper). They just don't work, even after a reboot and reload file in workspace.

Comment: you might want to give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76578004/11107541) a read