# How to enable CSS intellisense in JSX files in VSCode

Tags: reactjs, next.js, css-in-js, styled-jsx

I just got a new work computer, and setting up the dev environment, I cannot seem to get my Intellisense to work while in a React.jsx file

I'm using CSS-in-JS with NextJs styled JSX https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx

[image]

I've tried googling a lot and running out of sanity...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you try this extension?
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=blanu.vscode-styled-jsx

Comment: Yes, I tried that and the styled-components one.  No luck.  I had it working on my old work computer, so I know it's possible, and shouldn't be such a hard thing to enable.  but not sure why I can't get it working now.

Comment: Really tough to spot the problem without your environment :D

One other thing that comes to mind is that you might have some setting active that might get in the way of intellisense. Chick out this thread for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61171247/vscode-autocomplete-doesnt-work-for-css-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This extension did the trick
styled-jsx Language Server

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Divlo.vscode-styled-jsx-languageserver

Answer (score 0):

In order to get syntax highlighting & autocomplete, you need to install two extensions:

- Syntax highlighting - [vscode-styled-jsx](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=blanu.vscode-styled-jsx)
- Code completion - [styled-jsx Language Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Divlo.vscode-styled-jsx-languageserver)